# Send JSON data over 2000 characters

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, jsonp, getjson

Is that possible to send JSON data over 2000 chars?
My url length is 5260, and I get error GET 404().
Is there any solution to send this data in json?

```
 update: {
                    url: ServiceBase + "Coating/updateTestResult",
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        if (jqXHR.status == "200") {
                            showNotification("Alert", "Records updated.", "upload-success");
                        } else {
                            showNotification("Error", "Couldn't update records.", "info");
                        }
                    }
                }

 if (operation === "update") {
                        $.each(dataSource._data, function () {
                            var row = $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid='" + this.uid + "']");
                            if (row.hasClass("blur")) {
                                row.removeClass("blur");
                            }
                            this.dirty = false;
                        });

                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to perform a POST request instead. Max. URL length is 2000 chars ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers#417184)) that's why you get an error 404.

Comment: @user4810410 did you move the json into the body?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Not via URL. That's why I suggest POST request and your JSON as your passing data.